# How to adapt two floating divs in smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I am creating a list from a `JSON` with this `HTML` code

```css
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div.description {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.link {
  float: right;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row1,
.row2 {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list" id="dataList"></ul>
<div id="item">
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="description"></div>
    <div class="link"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The description could be long but the link is very short. In small screens the two divs are not parallel anymore and it's not possible to distinguish which link correspond to which description.

How can I fix this? I tried to use float left but the two divs are sometimes stuck together, sometimes not, and it does not look better. And I am not sure how to do that only for mobile devices.

I suppose that this is a well-known problem. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
In big screens it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnzyA.png) and I small screens it looks like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VkOI.png)

Comment: "are not parallel anymore": you mean one of the div gets a weird angle? sorry for that, anyway, can you please provide a verifiable example, or a screenshot of what's happening? your description is not very clear

Comment: research  `@media` rules in css

Comment: I added two screenshots

Comment: And which part of this blue text mess is supposed to be the description now, which the link …? Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Don’t just show pictures, use your words to _properly_ explain what the issue is.

Comment: The description is floating on the left, the link is floating on the right, is it so hard to identify?

Answer (score 0):

You can give some width to both elements like below:

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

div.description {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width:85%;
}

div.link {
  float: right;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 15%;
  text-align: right;
}

.row1,
.row2 {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list" id="dataList"></ul>
<div id="item">
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </div>
        <div class="link">Lorem</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may seem weird, but placing the right floating item before the content (in term of HTML order) and removing the `float: left;` from the description would solve your problem. I only added a little margin so that the link is a bit separated from description, or else it sticks to it.

Note: with this solution, no need to precise any width, it will adapt all sizes.

```css
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div.description {
  overflow: auto;
}

div.link {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row1,
.row2 {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list" id="dataList"></ul>
<div id="item">
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="link">Lorem</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image{display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle}
.image a img{width: 100%; max-width: 200px}
.content{vertical-align:middle; display:table-cell; width:400px;}
.content1{float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <div class="image">
        <a>
            <p>test</p>
             <img></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content1"><p>test</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```